# Filebeat on raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, camera

I wanna know if is it possible to install filebeat from elasticstack (I need it to get logs file from an indoor camera) on raspberry pi 3 and if yes does anyone have a tutorial or can teach me the process?

Comment: Only if an arm7 or arm8/arm64 version is available for linux -- or the source code, with which you might be able to compile it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture

Comment: There appears to be AARCH64 versions at https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/filebeat which might run OK on RaspiOS 64 on a RPi3 or RPi4.